# How to dynamically cast a boost::scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, dynamic-cast, c++98, scoped-ptr

I'm surprised the compiler refuses to compile this kind of code :

```
class A { virtual ~A() {} };
class B : public A { virtual ~B() {} void foo() {} };
//...
boost::scoped_ptr<A> p1(new B);
boost::scoped_ptr<B> p2 = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(p1);
p2->foo();
```

**Why this is not possible ? What is the best way to do that ?**

I found this solution :

```
boost::scoped_ptr<A> p1(new B);
B* p2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(p1.get());
p2->foo();
```

**Is there a way using intelligent pointers only ?**

*Note : I don't use  C++11 for compatibility reason.*

Comment: `boost::scoped_ptr` doesn't allow shared or transfer of ownership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p1` owns the `B` object, and will delete it in its destructor.  If you allowed the creation of a second smart pointer (`p2`) which was also going to delete the object in its destructor, you would have a problem.

Personally I would use a cast to a reference rather than a pointer, but apart from that, you have found the only solution.